# Two Instances' Attributes Refer to the Same Memroy Location in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, jupyter-notebook

How can this be possible in Python 3? k1 and k2's **a** attributes refer to the same memory location in IPython console

```
class K():

    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a


k1 = K(4)
k2 = K(4)

hex(id(k1)) # 0x10d77b668
hex(id(k2)) # 0x10d77b6a0

hex(id(k1.a)) # 0x10d41caa0
hex(id(k2.a)) # 0x10d41cac0

id(k1.a) == id(k2.a) # True
```

I am mostly concerned about the object reference issue going on here rather than the 'is' operator test, which I believe is not the problem I am trying to solve. Because, both k1.a and k2.a would pass the is test because the two references refer to the same object. But what I would like to know is, why that happens.

Comment: Both `a` attributes refer to an integer with the value 4, and small integer objects (-5 thru 256, I think)  are cached for efficiency.  If this makes any difference to your program, then your program is broken.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that happens. It is only a test. Nothing critical. Looks like your theory is correct. When the number is big, they are different. Is there any way to change this behavior?

Comment: That is not @jasonharper's "theory" that is a documented part of the CPython implementation: https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_FromLong

Comment: @c00der also, just so you know, instance variables, in general, won't have different `id` unless they are different objects, But if you did `some_object = object()` and then `k1 = K(some_object); k2 = K(some_obejct)`, then of course, `id(k1.a) == id(k2.a)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, thanks, yeah, I can see why that happens. There you reference the same object.